# Home network connection bottleneck

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I'm having strange timeouts in my home connection.

I have three devices in my home.

1. A cable modem (Arris
2. A WiFi router (NightHawk R7000) with the cable modem as gateway
3. My computer connected to WiFi router wirelessly on 5Ghz

Now, when I run applications at home I sometimes get network timeouts, and I want to know which device is the faulty one, assuming the connection to my ISP and Internet is just fine.

This is my network ping analysis:

[image]

and when I browse the internet I sometimes get that a huge timeout... I'm not sure though which device is causing the issue... the router and cable modem seem to work fine.

How can I debug this further?

Comment: What is the IP of your computer and which is the router? I presume `192.168.0.0/24` and `192.168.0.1` respectively... If that's true, then your local network is at fault... either your computer, the WiFi network, or the WiFi router. Can you share more information about your network channel and the RF utilisation (i.e: other devices on your network, or other nearby networks)?

Comment: Wifi issue. Try and get hold of a couple of powerline adapters

Comment: @JohnnyVegas do you recommend getting a newer/better Wifi router? Edit: Oh, I just learn about Powerline adapters... awesome!

Comment: @Attie 192.168.0.1 is the cable modem, 192.168.1.1 is my wifi router, and the last image is a ping to google.com

Comment: A better wifi router would make no difference and possibly be worse - The best wifi for range would be 80211-bgn. 5ghz+ never has good range, but 200+ speed though.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas, this really depends on the environment. I have two 802.11ac routers that replaced 802.11n-2.4Ghz ones. They outperform the 2.4Ghz in range and speed, 800+Mbps and range is a good 100ft past where the wireless-n devices would drop off. Having beam-forming capable devices seems to make a huge difference.

Comment: Try a site survey with a WiFi scanning app. Make sure you are on a non-congested channel. Check the logs, DFS channel interference should be in there if your router is experiencing it. If you see warnings about radar, or channel changing/probing messages, change to a non-DFS channel. I'm seeing zero packet loss to the R7000, and zero packet loss on the private side of the Arris. Does this happen when wired directly to the r7000 or Arris? If it does you should be looking at the modem SNR levels for upstream/downstream.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. It happened to be an issue with my ISP... which makes sense as there are no problems to my access point and gateway. The technicians ended up changing frequencies on the cable modem side - not exactly sure what.